# Convert timezone offset number of hours to timezone offset in (military?) hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I am using WordPress and jQuery Timepicker.

Wordpress gives timezone offset in hours: like +2 or -3.5

jQuery Timepicker takes offset in military hours: +0200 or -0330

I am currently using something like this:

```
gmt_offset = -4;
hrs_offset = gmt_offset.replace('-', '-0') + "00";

= -0400
```

But that will break if the offset is not a single negative digit.

```
gmt_offset = -3.5;
hrs_offset = gmt_offset.replace('-', '-0') + "00";

= -03.500  //No good...

need: -0330
```

Ack! Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: It will also break if you try "-11"

Comment: Indeed, -11 is not a single negative digit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the offset into 2 parts using `.split(".")`.

Give the hour part a "0" if it is less than 10. Then append a negative sign if it is originally negative.

```
var negative = hour < 0 ? true : false;
hour = Math.abs(hour) < 10 ? "0" + Math.abs(hour) : Math.abs(hour);
hour = negative ? "-" + hour : "+" + hour;
```

To calculate the minutes part, multiply it by 6.

```
(time[1]*6).toString()
```

Here's the final function:

```
function convertOffset(gmt_offset) {
    var time = gmt_offset.toString().split(".");
    var hour = parseInt(time[0]);
    var negative = hour < 0 ? true : false;
    hour = Math.abs(hour) < 10 ? "0" + Math.abs(hour) : Math.abs(hour);
    hour = negative ? "-" + hour : "+" + hour;
    return time[1] ? hour+(time[1]*6).toString() : hour + "00";
}
document.write(convertOffset(-3.5));
```

See [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uzikes/5/edit).

Comment: Isn't this missing the '+' for positive offsets?

Comment: This doesn't account for offsets such as Nepal time which have offsets such as 5.75. A couple of changes account for it. If you change the first line to `var time = gmt_offset.toFixed(2).split(".");` to ensure we are always working with two decimal places, and then change the final return line to `return time[1] ? hour+((time[1]/10)*6).toString() : hour + "00";` so we divide by 10 before multiplying by 6, this appears to give consistent results.

Answer (score 2):

```
function convert(gmt_offset) {
     var sign ="+";
     if(gmt_offset < 0) {
         sign="-";
         gmt_offset *= -1;
     }
     var hours = "0"+Math.floor(gmt_offset).toString();
     var minutes = "0"+(Math.round(gmt_offset % 1 * 60)).toString();
     return sign + hours.substr(hours.length - 2) + minutes.substr(minutes.length - 2);
}
```

Comment: I like your function better, though I prefer only one `var` statement at the top. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nicely compact version:

```
function militaryGMTOffsetFromNumeric(offset) {
   var dt = new Date(
      Math.abs(offset) * 3600000 + new Date(2000, 0).getTime()
   ).toTimeString();
   return (offset < 0 ? '-' : '+') + dt.substr(0,2) + dt.substr(3,2);
}
```

For example, `militaryGMTOffsetFromNumeric(-3.5)` returns `-0330`.